# arguments in if else java questions

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement

I have a homework problem but i'm stuck with the if..else code because I have no idea what i'm supposed to do there.

- Write a class that has two overloaded static methods, with the same
  name, for calculating payroll for a company.
- Use the If..Else structure
- If Regular payroll is less than 40 hours, there are 2 arguments –
  hours worked and payrate
- Else Overtime payroll  is equal to regular hours = 40 hours,
  overtime hours = extra hours, there are 3 arguments regular hours
  worked, payrate, and overtime hours
- The user will use the keyboard to enter the regular hours worked,
  payrate, and overtime hours - use the Scanner class.
- The formulas for calculating the regular payroll is: hours
  payrate*hours worked
- The formula for calculating overtime payroll is: payrate * hours
  worked + (overtime hours * 1.5)

I think i got the rest correct, but I'm kinda stuck with my if..else code because I don't know what it means by "there are 2 arguments". I understand what arguments are in Java but not in this context. here's what i have so far:

```
public class ifelse {

public static double calculatePayroll (double hoursPayrate, int hoursWorked)
{
return hoursPayrate * hoursWorked;
}

public static double calculatePayroll (double hoursPayrate, int hoursWorked, double overtimeHours)
{
return hoursPayrate * hoursWorked + (overtimeHours *1.5);
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        double hoursPayrate, overtimeHours;
        int hoursWorked;


        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the hours worked");
        hoursWorked = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the payrate ");
        hoursPayrate = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the overtime hours");
        overtimeHours = keyboard.nextInt();

    if (hoursWorked < 40)

    else (hoursWorked = 40)

    }
```

Comment: The "2 arguments" are then *enumerated* as "hours worked" and "payrate".

Comment: Use `{` `}` around the parts you want to run after each of `if` and `else`.  And get rid of the condition following `else`.  I also advise that you should learn the difference between `==` and `=` so that you can use them correctly in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(hoursWorked<40)
    calculatePayroll(hoursPayrate,hoursWorked);
else
    calculatePayroll(hoursPayrate,hoursWorked,overtimeHours);
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know it was this simple. :D